# Parse whole page when ready to add tooltips to specific words

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I have a database relation that consists of a simple `name: definition` glossary for technical terms. The rows are fetched by the server and sent to the application via AJAX.

My goal is, once the document is ready, to look in the entire page and replace occurrences of `name` with `<span title='definition'>name</span>`.

I have tried using JQuery's `:contains` but since I can't attach the selector to a specific element, `$(:contains('name'))` returns the elements containing the text and ALL parent elements up to `html` without any form of distinction...

Comment: Are you able to target specific elements within the page rather than a blanket document search?

Comment: Unfortunately there is text in a lot of different sections of the application, and there is no way to collectively target all elements containing text

Comment: Would it be fair to say to target all p, span and div? Then do regexp on the text within each.

Comment: It would be ok but it would miss some content, such as text between `li` or `a`. I think given the fact that there is no easy way to do what my question asks I might go back and try to avoid it altogether... Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute selector without an element specified.

```
$('[title="definition"]')
```

Comment: I am not trying to target elements with a `title` attribute, but to target specific text keywords and dynamically wrap them with `<span title=...` elements. Thanks for your time though!